# CSS scaling letter spacing proportionally to fluid font size

Tags: css

I'm using a technique for scaling text based on view width, [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/fluid-typography/). It uses a simple formula to smoothly scale within a set range (min/max) of font sizes, depending on the view width within a set range (min/max). It works very well.

But I'm confronting an issue with this and other techniques for fluid font size. If I set letter spacing to a constant value, it may break down visually. 1px letter spacing for a font displayed at 20px might not be ideal for when it displays at 50px.

There are also situations where a user might change the font size. It would be the same issue.

Is there a solid way to deal with this issue that is fluid, to make letter spacing proportional to the font size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `em` units to control the the spacing.

here is a possible reference: https://cssreference.io/property/letter-spacing/

Answer (score 0):

I tried using calc, along with view width:

```
letter-spacing: calc(1px + (10 - 1) * ((100vw - 320px) / (1440 - 320)));
```

It works, but I think using ems is better.